# Alternative for brackets before and after multiline Text (Responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive

i want to have a heading with brackets before and after my text.

To show you what i mean, i created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2cqyut1/
or right here:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.brackets {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid red;
    transform: translate(0%, 20%);
    z-index: 1;
}

.text {
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 6rem;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.text span {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="brackets"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>MORE</span><br>
    <span>ABOUT</span><br>
    <span>FUTURE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a better, other / responsive solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked something together for you (based on your jsfiddle).

The main differences are, that I flexed the container, and used relative values all across the board. Hope this helps you ;)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 0 5%;
  margin: 5%;
}
span {
  font-size: 14vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: min-content;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
span:first-child {
  margin-top: -.25em;
}
span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>MORE</span><br>
  <span>ABOUT</span><br>
  <span>FUTURE</span>
</div>
```